# Java: Gson custom serializer and deserializer special requirement

Tags: json, serialization, gson

I know how to implement JsonDeserializer and JsonSerializer, but here is what I want to do:

This is the setup:

```
public class classA
{
public String a;
public classB clazzB;
}

public class classB
{
public String c;
public String d;
public String e;
public String f;
}
```

I want to serialize (and deserialize analog to this) classA like this:

- when serializing classA it should serialize a part of classB with it aswell, say variables c and d

Since I know how to do that (using transient for e and f) here is the catch:

- c and d (the parts of classB that should be serialized with classA) should NOT be in a JSONObject, they should rather appear INLINE with the variable from classA

In essence the result should look something like this:

```
{"a":"something","c":"something", "d":"something"}
```

The problem I am having with JsonSerializer here is that there are 2 variables (could be more) I have to serialize from classB. If it were only one then I could just return a JSONPrimitive of the variable. I was thinking about using JsonTreeWriter in the serialize method but I doubt that can be done.

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Other than "You're doing it wrong" since you're basically saying you don't want to serialize your Objects into the actual JSON equivalent... you don't serialize `classB`, because that's not what you want. You want a single JSON object with fields from two of your Objects.

You can just write a custom Deserializer and Serializer for A and create the JSON you're trying to create.

```
class ClassA
{
    public String a = "This is a";
    public ClassB clazzB = new ClassB();
}

class ClassB
{
    public String c = "This is c";
    public String d = "This is d";
    public String e;
    public String f;
}


class ASerializer implements JsonSerializer<ClassA>
{

    public JsonElement serialize(ClassA t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc)
    {
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.addProperty("a", t.a);
        jo.addProperty("c", t.clazzB.c);
        jo.addProperty("d", t.clazzB.d);
        return jo;
    }

}

public class Test 
{
    pubic static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        gson.registerTypeAdapter(ClassA.class, new ASerializer());
        String json = gson.create().toJson(new ClassA());
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

> {"a":"This is a","c":"This is c","d":"This is d"}

You could also go the route of serializing `ClassB` in that serializer, adding the elements in `ClassA` and returning that.